# terraform import fargate cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an existing manually created fargate cluster named "test-cluster" in us-west-1

In terraform configuration file i created

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "mycluster" {

}
```

I run terraform command to import the files

```
terraform import aws_ecs_cluster.mycluster test-cluster
```

I receive this error message

Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object

While attempting to import an existing object to aws_ecs_cluster.cluster, the
provider detected that no object exists with the given id. Only pre-existing
objects can be imported; check that the id is correct and that it is
associated with the provider's configured region or endpoint, or use
"terraform apply" to create a new remote object for this resource.

I've also ran aws configure adding the correct region.

Comment: You need to define required parameters at minimum and the values have to match the ones you're trying to import, e.g. `name = "your-cluster-name"`.

Comment: If the region is correct, maybe account is not?

Comment: It turns out it was looking at the wrong account.

Comment: Just like I suspected. If you don't mind, I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by using **wrong account** in terraform and/or AWS console.

The **solution** was to use correct account.